# How to add ring (level) in twopi layout of pygraphviz in python?

Tags: python, graphviz, levels, pygraphviz

There are four rings (levels) of twopi layout in pygraphviz:

[image]

How to edit the attribute of the graph to add rings or levels of twopi layout?

Here are the codes of setting twopi attributes.
G_pgv.graph_attr.update(root='USA',ranksep='3.0',nodesep='2.0')
G_pgv.draw('pytry.jpg',prog='twopi')

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**twopi** picks a **root** node then lays the remaining node radially, based on the distance (in hops) from the **root**.  If you want another "ring/level/rank", add another hop (another intermediate edge).  Invisible edges also work.
p.s. you can explicitly set the **root** node.